# Masked out large irregular shape from image with Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, mask

The objective is to remove large irregular area and maintained only character in the image.

For example, given the following

[image]

and the expected `masked output`

[image]

I have the impression this can be achieved as below

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

dpath='remove_bg1.jpg'

img = cv2.imread(dpath)

img_fh=img.copy()
cv2.bitwise_not(img_fh,img_fh)
ksize=10
kernel = np.ones((ksize,ksize),np.uint8)
erosion = cv2.erode(img_fh,kernel,iterations = 3)
invertx = cv2.bitwise_not(erosion)
masked = cv2.bitwise_not(cv2.bitwise_and(img_fh,invertx))

all_image=[img,invertx,masked]
ncol=len(all_image)
for idx, i in enumerate(all_image):
    plt.subplot(int(f'1{ncol}{idx+1}')),plt.imshow(i)

plt.show()
```

which produce

[image]

Clearly, the code above did not produced the expected result.

May I know how to address this issue properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the unwanted blob, we must create a mask such that it encloses it completely.

#### Flow:

1. Inversely **binarize** the image (such that you have a white foreground against dark background)
2. **Dilate** the image (since the blob makes contact with letter 'A', it has to be isolated )
3. **Find contour** with the largest area
4. **Draw the contour** on an another 1-channel image and **thicken** it (dilation)
5. **Pixel Assignment**: Pixels containing the dilated blob are made white on the original image

#### Code:

```
im = cv2.imread('stained_text.jpg')
im2 = im.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# inverse binaraization
th = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
```

[image]

Notice the blob region touching the letter 'A'. Hence to isolate it we perform erosion using an elliptical kernel

```
# erosion
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5,5))
erode = cv2.erode(th, kernel, iterations=2)
```

[image]

```
# find contours
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(erode, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
# Contour of maximum area
c = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)

# create 1-channel image in black 
black = np.zeros((im.shape[0], im.shape[1]), np.uint8)
# draw the contour on it
black = cv2.drawContours(black, [c], 0, 255, -1)
# perform dilation to have clean border
# we are using the same kernel
dilate = cv2.dilate(black, kernel, iterations = 3)
```

[image]

```
# assign the dilated area in white over the original image
im2[dilate == 255] = (255,255,255)
```

[image]

> This was just one of the many possible ways on how to proceed. The key thing to note is how to isolate the blob.

Comment: Thanks @Jeru for the detail explanation, really appreciate it

Comment: @rpb I'm having trouble trying to analyse individual images. It would be helpful if you can add some images here